# javac show error without warnings

Tags: java, javac

I'm using Sun's javac 1.6.0_26. I invoke it like this:

```
javac -Xlint -encoding UTF-8
```

and usually if there are errors only them are displayed. However this code

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date();
        system.out.println(d.getDate());
    }
```

produces both warning and error:

```
java:5: warning: [deprecation] getDate() in java.util.Date has been deprecated
        system.out.println(d.getDate());
                            ^
java:5: package system does not exist
        system.out.println(d.getDate());
```

So my question is: how do I make javac show only errors (without warnins) when there are any and all warnings when there are no errors (never both)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a standard option in javac `-nowarn`which disable warning messages. You can get more informations from [javac-options](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html)

Comment: Having said that you shouldn't force compiler to disable all warnings. Instead, use SuppressWarnings where you think that can't be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea to ignore the compiler warnings. Most of the time they are really important. Only if you are very sure that you want to ignore a warning you can add an annotation:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
System.out.println(d.getDate());
```

It's like you are thinking: *Let me first fix errors and afterwards the warnings.* But I don't think that is a nice way of working. To solve warnings, you **might** have to change a lot of code, and all your other error-solving work was unneeded because you needed other code. It is always good the look at a problem globally.

Comment: a better way is to use javac commandline option, i guess.I'm a beginner, enlighten me if am wrong!

Comment: @Sanjay: In my opinion you are indeed wrong. I'm programming for about four years and I never wanted to turn it off. Warnings are important. If you tell the compiler to not show warnings, all new warnings the developer should get aren't shown, because you wanted to suppress one single warning.

Comment: @sanjay An annotation is specific to a deprecation, and communicates that the developer is very deliberately choosing to use deprecated code. The compiler switch ignores *all* deprecations, and may hide a  deprecation that the dev didn't mean to ignore.

Comment: But the question was  how do I make javac show only errors ,anyway I greatly appreciate your clarification. Thannks a lot ~!

Comment: I disagree with @MartijnCourteaux.  Just because *you* have never wanted to turn it off doesn't mean it's a bad thing.  I've never wanted to turn it off either, until today.  I'm working on a huge project with hundreds of committers.  I can't control their workflow and I certainly can't go throw `@SuppressWarnings` all over their code, but I can't find my build errors because they're hidden in a few thousand warnings.

Comment: @Hounshell: Too be honest, good code contains no errors and no warnings at all. So tell your coworkers to take care of warnings. Where "take care of" is not simply adding a `@SuppressWarnings`, but actually fixing the root of the warning. Many others have the same spirit: good code doesn't produce compiler warnings. For example, Eclipse shows you in the package explorer which files have warnings, but not only the files, it goes all the way up to the package and finally the whole project. Here is what I mean: http://i.stack.imgur.com/p4pwl.gif It just hates you for having warnings in your code.

Comment: Re: Good code conatins no warnings - That's great.  I agree with you on that point; my code doesn't have warnings, appropriate things are annotated.  But it ignores the reality of working with other people on code.  I don't have the clout (nor would I exercise it at this stage of the product) to get everyone involved to fix their warnings.  I do need to fix my issue though.  So I have two options: 1.) spend a couple days annotating every single warning with code I can't check in anyway because it's all code owned by other people, or 2.) temporarily hide the warnings with a compiler flag.

Comment: @Hounshell: Agreed on that. But that should only be a temporarily solution. However, you are right: I don't know anything about working with other people, since I'm only 18 years old...