# how to filter warnings from console in java when using deprecated api

Tags: java, swing

I am using deprecated methods such as getLabel() and setLabel() in swing.
After compiling the code,i am getting a whole lot of warnings and 1 error.
But due to the abundance of warnings on my console,i am unable to see the error specification on the console.
Is there any way to filter these warnings ??

Here is the data on console.

```
                                                                ^



                                  ^
    Ga.java:262: warning: [deprecation] getLabel() in AbstractButton has been deprec
    ated
                     if(b[0][1].getLabel()==" ")
                               ^

Ga.java:264: warning: [deprecation] getLabel() in AbstractButton has been deprec
ated
                         b[0][1].setLabel(b[1][1].getLabel());
                                                 ^
Note: Ga.java has additional uses or overrides of a deprecated API.
1 error
100 warnings
```

Comment: real developers don't ignore deprecation warnings

Comment: And they check the API for details.

Comment: @wero ,i agree with you.But is there is a way to filter them??

Comment: @asad: Don't know. If you can change the code base than it is simply better to fix the warning. It does not take much longer than to post a question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javac show error without warnings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777618/javac-show-error-without-warnings)

Comment: and they don't compile with javac manually anymore

Answer (score 1):

You can use this line before that method that uses the deprecated code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
```

**eg:** If you have it in the main method then:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void main(String args[])
{
    //code.
}
```